# How to serialize the custom object you are sending in JMS convertAndSend method

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jms

I am using the below mentioned code to publish into a topic. It is of the format convertAndSend(Destination destination, Object message)
So I understood upon reading the documentation that the object we are sending should be serialized.

```
    Event event;
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(topic, event);
```

My current Event interface is something like this,

```
public interface Event {

  public boolean isEmpty();

}
```

Its implementation is something like this,

```
public class EventPublisherImpl implements Event {
    private final TransactionRecord transactionRecord;
    //.....
    //@overriden methods

}
```

So right now they are not serialized, right?

Can I make the interface serializable by making the interface extend the Serializable?

My whole objective is to publish Event object into topic. For that I am using convertAndSend method. That method requires an object of a serialized class, which I currently dont have. It is what I am trying to achieve. 
Is my above mentioned approach, right?

Comment: Take a look at the sample project: [Messaging with JMS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/). Note that the object they transfer is not Serializable. They write: _The default MessageConverter is able to convert only basic types (such as String, Map, Serializable) and our Email is not Serializable on purpose. We want to use Jackson and serialize the content to json in text format (i.e. as a TextMessage)._

Comment: I know they have used messageconverter to convert into JSON but I dont need to convert into JSON. I am not transmitting over http or some network. So I dont need JSON format.

Comment: Thats the reason I have proposed, can we just extend my interface with serializable? Would that be enough for the method to work?